# How to escape single quote in bash with command using sed assigned to variable

Tags: mysql, bash, sed

I have a bash script that uses zcat, grep and cut to get the "subject" from gzipped quarantined emails. Then I store the "subject" in  a variable by using echo and sed to escape characters in the subject prior to using that stored subject in a mysql INSERT statement to store the "Subject" in a mysql table.

The problem I am having is that my current statement replaces single quotes with an ampersand and I cant add the single quote to the beginning of the sed because it needs to be escaped itself but I read that I cannot escape a single quote in a sed statement that is enclosed in single quotes.

Here is the relevant portion of the bash script

```
    Subject=`zcat $RCPT | grep -m2 Subject | tail -n1 | cut -d ":" -f 2`
    Subject2=`echo $Subject | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,._()+!#$?@%/-]/\\&/g; 1{$s/^$/""/}; 1!s/^/"/; $!s/$/"/'`

    mysql statement that inserts '$Subject2' in to a table
```

I figure that I can add the escaped single quote if I change the sed statement to be enclosed within double quotes but then I don't know how to change the second half of the sed command where the double quotes already exist.

Comment: Can you give some input/output examples -- what you are getting and what it is you want but aren't getting?

Comment: so the first line gets a subject like " Don't wait for your engine to lock up" (without the quotes). and the second line tries to escape characters like question marks etc so that the mysql INSERT statement doesnt throw an error when inserting that subject in to the database but gets this as a result "Don&t wait for your engine to lock up" (without the quotes)

examples:
input:  Don't wait for your engine to lock up
output: Don&t wait for your engine to lock up

input: Children's face glow with joy when they see this
output: Children&s face glow with joy when they see this

Comment: If you have *any* doubts at all about how to quote this correctly, you should not be using the shell to prepare an SQL statement. Use a language that provides a proper SQL library that can create and execute parameterized query.

Comment: Just break the single quotes at that place: `sed 's/'"'"'/a/g; s/a/b/g' <<< "Don't be sad"` or `sed 's/'\''/a/g; s/a/b/g' <<< "Don't be sad"`.

Comment: I also don't understand what you are trying to do with this stuff: `1{$s/^$/""/}; 1!s/^/"/; $!s/$/"/'`

Comment: That part is a mistake. it should read

        Subject2=`echo $Subject | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,._()+!#$?@%/-]/\\&/g'`

If i change the single quotes to double quotes how can i add an escaped single quote to the ,._()+!#$?@%/-] section?

Comment: OK -- I don't know what the second part of the `sed` command is about, but you can have different parts in different commands with `-e`, some with single quotes and some with double: `sed -e "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,._()+!#$?@%/-']/\\&/g" -e 's/fred/barney' -e "s/wilma/betty"`